# How to access the scene from within a component in A-Frame?

Tags: aframe

How to get the scene, from within a component `.init()` function in A-Frame?

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('foo', {
  init: function () {
    // ?
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://aframe.io/docs/0.4.0/core/component.html#component-prototype-properties

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('foo', {
  init: function () {
    console.log(this.el.sceneEl);
  },

  update: function () {
    console.log(this.el.sceneEl);
  }
});
```